# Connection pool has been closed in Sqlite Azure Mobile Service SDK

Tags: android, database, sqlite, connection, azure-mobile-services

In my Android project i use Azure Mobile Services SDK and the way i make queries to the local sqlite database is like the following:
(example taken from http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-data/).

The problem is that i get the following errors: 
1)com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.localstore.MobileServiceLocalStoreException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed

2) A SQLiteConnection object for database 'LocalDatabase' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed

3) java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.sync.localstore.MobileServiceLocalStoreException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        final MobileServiceList<ToDoItem> result = mToDoTable.where().field("complete").eq(false).execute().get();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mAdapter.clear();

                for (ToDoItem item : result) {
                    mAdapter.add(item);
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        createAndShowDialog(exception, "Error");
    }
    return null;
  }
}.execute();
```

In this implementation there is no Cursor or SQLiteOpenHelper object to close. What could i do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are getting the result in one thread but trying to use that same result in the UI thread. One possible method is to use Broadcast or Eventbus to send the data back to the UI once the operation completes:

Here is sort of what I would do:

```
  Futures.addCallback(mToDoTable.where().field("complete").eq(false).execute(), new FutureCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Object result) {
                                //Do something with result
                                //I would use event bus or broadcast here to notify the UI
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

                            }
                });
```

If this doesn't work, I would use the debugger and put a break point on that execute().get() line and see what is happening internally.

Here is another possible way to do it:

```
   mToDoTable.where().field("complete").eq(false).execute(new TableQueryCallback<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(List result, int count, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {

                    }
                });
```